# Is there a way in pandas to group rows in a dataframe based on a quantity in one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I have a dataframe like this:

| ID | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 10 |
| BBB | 30 |
| CCC | 30 |
| DDD | 10 |
| EEE | 20 |

Is there a way to add a "group" column so that I can create groups of similar quantity?

Like, if I wanted groups whose quantity sum would be ~50 (does not have to be exact):

| ID | Quantity | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 10 | 1 |
| BBB | 30 | 1 |
| CCC | 30 | 2 |
| DDD | 10 | 1 |
| EEE | 20 | 2 |

Or groups whose quantity sum would be ~30:

| ID | Quantity | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 10 | 1 |
| BBB | 30 | 2 |
| CCC | 30 | 3 |
| DDD | 10 | 1 |
| EEE | 20 | 1 |

I have a very large amount of data that I would like to process in batches but need to ensure that the sum of the quantity column in each batch is roughly equal.

I hope this question is fairly clear. Thank you **very** much in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may want to reword your question because you are not really doing a "group by" in the traditional sense, but rather, want to assign a column GROUP and assign a group number to each range. You should also be more specific in what your Range's need to be. I'll post a example in a minute.

Comment: Are you looking for an optimal solution? It looks like the [Multiple Knapsacks](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/multiple_knapsack). This is an NP-complete problem. If you just want a solution, it can be easy but slow.

Comment: OMG, thank you. @Corralien is 100% correct that this is like the Multiple Knapsacks _except_ I didn't have an upper limit of the number of "knapsacks". In fact, I was completely overthinking it but you led me to an answer I'll post below.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comment above, I was completely overthinking this but the comments here really helped me out.

I have a dataset of 150,000,000 events in 55,000 categories. I needed to process that data in batches, but *I had to ensure that all of the events in a category were processed in the same batch* (although a batch could contain multiple categories.)

As stated in the original question, I had a dataframe of events grouped by category with three columns: `id`, `category`, `event_count`. `event_count` was just a sum of all of the event rows in a specific category.

I ended up just writing a crummy Python loop that added categories to a group until the sum of event_count in that group was > 1,500,000 (an arbitrary number to divide the dataset into 100 groups).

```
group_counter = 1
event_counter = 0
for i in event.index:
  event_counter += event.loc[i, "event_count"]
  if event_counter < 1500000:
    event.loc[i, "category"] = int(group_counter)
  else:
    event_counter = row.event_count
    group_counter += 1
    event.loc[i, "category"] = int(group_counter)
```

Super stupid and there's probably a million better ways to do it but this was exactly what I needed.

I was overthinking it and the reminder of the [Multiple Knapsacks](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/multiple_knapsack) problem was a perfect nudge.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @corrilien, there are more efficient solutions. I would probably throw all the logic into a function and apply that instead of doing everything in line.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'ID': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE'], 
        'Quantity': [10, 30, 30, 10, 20]
       }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
    ID  Quantity
0  AAA        10
1  BBB        30
2  CCC        30
3  DDD        10
4  EEE        20

>>> df['Group'] = df.apply(lambda row: 3 if row.Quantity > 29 else (1 if row.Quantity <= 10 else 2), axis=1)
>>> df
    ID  Quantity  Group
0  AAA        10      1
1  BBB        30      3
2  CCC        30      3
3  DDD        10      1
4  EEE        20      2
```